# How to modify the path of SKShapeNode on the fly?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skshapenode

somewhere in didMove I am creating `SKShapeNode` :

```
path.move(to: points.first!)

let linearShapeNode = SKShapeNode()
linearShapeNode.path = path
linearShapeNode.strokeColor = .black
linearShapeNode.lineWidth = 3.0
linearShapeNode.lineCap = .round
someSprite.addChild(linearShapeNode)
```

path is class member:

```
var path: CGMutablePath
```

Then in `update` method of scene I am adding lines to the path:

```
path.addLine(to: points[index])
```

I expect to see new lines drawn on the sprite. However, no new lines appear. If after addLine I re-assign path to SKShapeNode's path, then I see it. But it doesn't look optimal to draw all over again.

What is the proper way of updating path on SKShapeNode? What I am trying to achieve is to see new line segment each half second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't update the path, you can only replace it with a new path (even if it means taking a copy of the path, making it mutable, and then reassigning it back to your node)

SKShapeNode uses a copy of the path you assign to it, so even if you use a mutable path, you will not see the changes.

The easiest thing for you to do is after you make your path change, assign it once more to your shape.

Comment: and the difficult thing is to use stroke shader to animate path?